# Make git-submodule update from specific Host in config

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules

Using this guide [here](https://medium.com/@xiaolishen/use-multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer-7d7103ca8693) I have created a work ssh-key (`id_rsa_work`) and changed my `config` file to

```sh
# Personal GitHub account
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 User git
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Work GitHub account
Host github.com-work
 HostName github.com
 User git
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

I have added the work ssh to my work git-repo and I can call
`git clone git@github.com-work:user/test.git` and clone it.

The problem is that there is a submodule in `test` which I cannot update, calling

```
git submodule update
```

throws the error

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:user/Utils.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/user/Documents/work/test/Utils' failed
```

It seems like it tries to pull using my personal setting (`git@github.com`) and not the work (`git@github.com-work`). I have called `git submodule init` and have tried modify the `.gitmodule` url to

```
[submodule "Utils"]
    path = Utils
    url = git@github.com-work:user/Utils.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

After calling `git submodule update` change the URL (for some reason it does not change, eventhough I change the `.gitconfig` file) by

(assume you are in the `test` folder)

```sh
git submodule set-url ./Utils/ "git@github.com-work:user/Utils.git"
git update
cd Utils
git checkout master
```

Comment: The touchy part is that a submodule's url is intended to be committed and shared. You can live with a locally modified `.gitmodules` file, and be careful not to commit it, it just adds one thing to be aware of when committing/pushing.

Comment: If "work" should be your default setup, and "github.com" the one you want when working on other stuff, you may switch the two `Host` names in your .ssh/config