# Access different github accounts from different git local config

Tags: github, github-actions, git

Here there are two different users in github.com

- "user-one" (one@mail.com)
- "user-two" (two@mail.com)

Each user has its own repositories with different projects within them accounts

- https://github.com/user-one/repo-one.git
- https://github.com/user-two/repo-two.git)

Now there is me from my computer: I want to set local configurations to

- "folder-one" targeting repo-one to upload project changes, so:

  - git config --local user.name "user-one"
  - git config --local user.email one@mail.com
- "folder-two" targeting repo-two to upload project changes, so:

  - git config --local user.name "user-two"
  - git config --local user.email two@mail.com

When I push to "repo-one" GitHub installs a credential in my computer (like git:https://github.com) that let me only to upload changes to that repo.

**The problem**

I can solve this erasing that credential each time I push to different repos, but there is a better way to do this? some way to save each new user data in place of rejecting me the access?

**Solution proponsal**

How to let GitHub know that I will handle different accounts that will push to them each own differents repos?

Answer (score 0):

To push with two different accounts :

One way could be : define two `Host` sections in your local `.ssh/config`, which will both target github, but use different keys :

```
Host ghuser1
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile path/to/user1/publickey

Host ghuser2
    ...
```

You can then set two remotes to `ghuser1:[user]/[repo]` and `ghuser2:[user]/[repo]`

[edit] dug out this more detailed link on medium : [Use multiple ssh-keys for different GitHub accounts](https://medium.com/@xiaolishen/use-multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer-7d7103ca8693)
from this other SO question : [Make git-submodule update from specific Host in config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769787/make-git-submodule-update-from-specific-host-in-config)

---

note that `user.name` and `user.email` are used to write the commit author on each commit. Keep these values to the author you want to have in your history.

Comment: The "Host + .ssh/config" is like Im looking for. I will dig on that.